# File management best practices

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, wcf

Hi I am currently working on a WPF application which needs extensive file management (users should be able to upload files to a central server and download files from that server) 
currently i have created a fairly simple wcf based server to handle these requests.

i was wondering if there are any better ways to do this like third party apps or features in windows server, sql server, wpf that i am not aware of ...

Comment: You are wonderung if there are any better ways to do WHAT? It seems like you are inventing FTP?!?

Comment: well i guess what i am looking for is a third party tool that runs on the server and handles these requests that way i wouldn't need to worry about the concurrency issues, possible exceptions, bandwidth allocations ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql Server 2012 Has a new Feature on Top of FileStream, it's called FiledTables.

There you also have a fileshare which is syncronized with your filetable

[Tutorial](http://sqlsailor.com/2012/03/12/file-table-in-sql-server-2012-great-flexibility-to-manage-filestream-data/)

Answer (score 0):

For storing: Read about `FILESTREAM` capabilities in SQL Server 2008 for storing and accessing large files in SQL just thru file system.

For uploading/downloading: have no clue for you right now..

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using WebDAV with IIS?

Comment: Not really ... but i like to explore my options can you give me some references ?